# Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500

Tags: wireless-mouse

I am trying to download the software necessary to use my Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500, but I get an error screen saying:

"not a valid Win32 application." But my computer is 64-bits and Windows 7. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

usually, that means a corrupt download.

Try from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/wireless-mobile-mouse-3500) and remember to select the correct OS